# Is it possible to insert an Excel Chart in Word as editable graphics?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vector-graphics

I would like to rework Excel Charts as simple shapes as can be created by hand in Word.

The only options to paste a chart to Word seems to be by embedding and linking, and they remain Excel objects.

Instead, I would like them to be editable graphics made of individual shapes. I don't want to retain the original relation to Excel data.

Any hint ?

---

**Update:**

I found the menu entry Paste special…, which supplies different As picture options and As a Microsoft Office Object (with the comment Inserts the contents of the Clipboard as shapes). Much to my disappointment, the latter still inserts as an non-editable Excel chart.

The option Picture (enhanced metafile) does what I want, though the graphical quality seems degraded, and most of the grouping is lost.

Could there be yet another way ?

Comment: FWIW I had a long look around this problem a few days ago and couldn’t see any copy/paste or export option that would give you the fully editable diagram without the excel sheet. If you look at the object model for the chart object it becomes clear that the individual graphic elements (e.g. bars) are not directly represented in the model, I.e. the graphics are generated on-the-fly, so it isn’t even possible to “roll your own” export by copying the graphic elements into a new diagram one by one. You’d basically have to generate the entire diagram yourself from the data, diagram type etc.

Comment: @yokki: I see, this is quite believable. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to insert an editable chart is using Insert > Chart feature directly. You can pick up a chart type and modify chart data in Word instead of using external data sources / links. You can also format the chart using build-in options in Word.

[image]

If you have created a Excel Chart, I think you can copy the data source of chart and paste it into Word's Excel chart editor, then format the chart as you want.

For more information, read [Add a chart to your document in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-chart-to-your-document-in-word-ff48e3eb-5e04-4368-a39e-20df7c798932) and [Insert a chart from an Excel spreadsheet into Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-a-chart-from-an-excel-spreadsheet-into-word-0b4d40a5-3544-4dcd-b28f-ba82a9b9f1e1).

Comment: I have tried that. The chart is still linked to the data and you cannot edit the shapes.